# Package 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have made .net core 2.0 web app. I have added Entity Framework 6.2.0 using NUGET and then I get this error

> Package 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is your entity version is confused with `.NetFramework` and `.NetCore`. Your application target framework is `Asp.Net Core`. So You should install package related with  `Asp.net Core`

In your case `'EntityFramework 6.2.0'` is supports by `.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'` not by  `'.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'`. So use this below version of entity framework instead of yours.

```
PM>  Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.0.1
```

#### 3rd party

If Nuget is not installed this command should do it

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Comment: Current is 2.2.2 Run without -Version if you whant latest one.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can change your target framework to net461 as below.

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

By changing your target framework to net461 makes you available to use .net core and full .net frameworks. I think that for this period of time, this approach is better. Because EF Core still hasn't got some main features like [many to many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) and some others. Sure it depends on your needs and expectations from an ORM tool.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my project was Core 2.2.  I installed (NuGet) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v2.2.4 first and all built fine.  Then I ACCIDENTALLY installed Microsoft.AspNet.Identity rather than Microsoft.AspNetCore.Idendity (v2.2.0).  Once my eyes spotted the missing 'Core' in the .Identity package and I fixed it by uninstalling the wrong and installing the right, then the warnings went away.  I expect I'm not the only one that went a little fast on the Nuget installations on a new project :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your project to `.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1` or choose an Entity Framework nuget that supports `.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was introduced by altering my solution to use a new TargetFramework.

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

After the Update I tried to add the Identity Framework but failed with a warning as described.

By Adding the packages in this sequence solved it for me:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```